# substring isn't working as expected on innerHtml

Tags: javascript, substring, innerhtml

The string i'm working on is "innerHtml", i want to extract from it a substring starting from the index *0* until index *limit*.

In Javascript , the method :
`string.substring(startIndex, endIndex)` allows to extract a substring  starting  with the start index and finishing with endIndex.

i Typed on my  rich conteant div this:
<b>B</b>

after applying substring on the innerHtml i get this: <b></b>

this is the js :

```
    const target = document.querySelector('#RichText')
    

    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const withinBoundaries = event.composedPath().includes(target)
       
        if (!withinBoundaries && !withinBoundaries2 && !withinBoundaries3 && !withinBoundaries4)     {
            target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML.substring(0, 3);
        }
        alert(target.innerHTML.length + target.innerHTML)
    })
```

what is wrong ?

Comment: What is wrong? IDK Too, What your expected answer.

Comment: the expected answer is <b>B

Comment: substring - subtract the string inside your `<b></b>` html element. Not the html itself
That why it is call substring

Comment: innerHtml is a string not ?

Comment: `<b> </b>` these are **HTML** element not string. 
`<b>    >>> strings  <<<   </b>` inside are strings

Comment: Did my answer works for you?

Comment: no , it lacks how to convert innerHtml on a string to substring it and then reconverting back to html

Comment: I just update my answer, Hope this will help. I am using regex to ignore the html tags

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you set the innerHTML to "<b>" ??? Just a <b> by itself id invalid HTML and browser corrects it when you set the html

Comment: `console.log("<b>B</b>".substring(0,3));` is `<b>` not `<b>b`

Comment: we count from 0 man not from 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Khant said innerHTML is html, so what was missing is encode from html to string and decode from string to html:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const withinBoundaries = event.composedPath().includes(target)
        const withinBoundaries2 = event.composedPath().includes(target2)
        const withinBoundaries3 = event.composedPath().includes(target3)
        const withinBoundaries4 = event.composedPath().includes(target4)
        
        if (!withinBoundaries && !withinBoundaries2 && !withinBoundaries3 && !withinBoundaries4) {

            var str = htmlencode(target.innerHTML);
            var innerHTML = $.parseHTML(htmldecode(str.substring(0, limit)));
            $('#RichText').html(innerHTML);
            
        }
    })
    

       
    function htmlencode(str) {

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
        return div.innerHTML;
    }
    function htmldecode(str) {

        var txt = document.createElement('textarea');
        txt.innerHTML = str;
        return txt.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, You probably want to save your innterhtml to a string first
then use `str.replace` method on your converted string.

Then you will want to substring the result, **GOOD LUCK**

```
if (!withinBoundaries && !withinBoundaries2 && !withinBoundaries3 && !withinBoundaries4) {
           var str = target.innerHTML;
           str = str.replace(/<.*>(.*)<\/.*>/g, "$1")
           var res = str.substring(0, 3);
    }

alert(res)
```

Comment: no man the div should  contain html not string, in other words i want to cut a portion of the innerHTML not cuting the string inside